# What should be the return type of WCF Service for large amount of data and wth different clients?

Tags: java, c#, android, wcf, wcf-binding

I have created a WCF service whose return type is Dataset which is .NET framework compatible clients. But now my requirement gets changed and the clients can be platform independent i.e. service can be consumed by JAVA, Android phones and .NET application.

My questions are:

1. Which data type should  I use which is compatible to all clients? i.e. JAVA don't have dataset as type(not much knowledge on JAVA)
2. service that I've created is default one provided by .NET framework(NOT REST, not using SOAP manually)
3. Data will be of thousand lines which return type will be better ?
4. DO I have to use REST,SOAP for large amount of data ?
5. how can I achieve this?

please don't mark this question as DUPLICATE!

Comment: And if it was a duplicate, why should we not mark it as such?

Comment: @MartinKonecny why should one avoid SOAP, other than buzzword fanatistm `"lolol REZTT LOL"`, please?

Comment: @ThorstenDittmar you can but my question is complicated not much general

Comment: @MartinKonecny by using REST I can send tabular data ?(i.e. currently I am sending the dataset to .NET client) but how to JAVA client and also ANDROID ? I mean how they consume if I won't change return type as dataset? I want to make service like that any client can consume it

Comment: @highscore Java is a bit more than just Android - he could want to write a desktop application...

Comment: @dirtydeveloper questions are not marked as duplicates based on their level of complexity, but when they've been answered before.

Comment: @ThorstenDittmar I am new to stack overflow and don't know much about it but my title seems to be common and like it was answered before  but not the actual question. anyway Thanks! I've just learned something.

Comment: all of you please stop fighting and give clarifications of my question. please

Comment: @DirtyDeveloper - you may want to consider using JSON + REST. JSON is very elegant if a little inefficient in sending data, however for small amounts of data (less than 1MB) it's fine. If you are sending multiple MB's of data, you can either paginate your JSON response, or use a binary serialization protocol. More here: http://theburningmonk.com/2013/09/binary-and-json-serializer-benchmarks-updated/

Comment: @MartinKonecny I agree with your above statement about JSON + REST, that's the immediate first choice. My advice still stands to use Xamarin because A: Xamarin is really cross platform, java is not, and B: java is a horrible language. .Net/Xamarin make things easy, while java is very painful to work with.

Comment: @MartinKonecny thanks for the suggestion ! I am looking into that.

Comment: @HighCore agree with you ,JAVA is very painful.:)

Comment: Breaking a leg is painful. Using Java when used to C#/.net is simply a matter of willingness to learn something new. Language wars aren't helpful. Your requirement is to deliver data to non-.net clients, so deal with it. Martin gave you some good resource on how to do it. This is not meant to be offensive - just tired of that old "Language XY is painful" - wining.

Answer (score 0):

For large amount of data you should consider the followings:

1. Try to use some kind of compression. I usually use 7zip's open source compression to reduce the data transfer.
2. Use and share well defined DTO (Data Transfer Objects) on both server and clients.
3. Use streams to transfer your data and parse them correctly.
4. If you have less DTOs and large data in the objects, you can use SOAP otherwise stick to REST.

Comment: Thanks for the response. I cannot use Compression and streams as of now. consider I m having 1000 product data rows (previously I was using datset as return type) how can I transfer the data using WCF then? return type? and if by using SOAP then how? any pointers please

Comment: I do not think its a good idea to send datarows or datasets just like that over WCF. That is what I have explained in my answer that you need to make proper DTOs.

Comment: can I use List<object> as return type. I have read some of the threads  which says it's not good to use list<objet>. what will be the return type? using default WCF will return SOAP so do I have to change anything else?

Comment: @DirtyDeveloper ... Please understand when I said that you need to make your own DTOs. Imagine if you are consuming this web service on PHP, how would you convert List<object> ? Its better to create your own list/array or objects for DT.

Comment: I want to support for all clients including JAVA,android and NET applications. if I return strongly typed List<Products> will it be consumable by other clients? for NET I am sure it will work but for others I don't have much idea! that's why I mentioned List<object>

Comment: If its convert-able to a soap message, its really going to be used in any language. Down the road, you are just sending and receiving XMLs